Traefik Default Certificate being assigned over my LCN Certificate
Treafik version 2.5
Traefik.toml file
# Entry Points Configuration
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.websecure.http.tls]

# Providers Configuration
[providers]
  [providers.docker]
    endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault = false

# TLS Certificates Configuration
[tls]
  [[tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "/certs/certificate.crt"
    keyFile = "/certs/private.key"
    stores = ["default"]

# TLS Stores Configuration
[tls.stores]
  [tls.stores.default]
    [tls.stores.default.defaultCertificate]
      certFile = "/certs/certificate.crt"
      keyFile  = "/certs/private.key"

# TLS Options Configuration
[tls.options]
  [tls.options.default]
    minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
    maxVersion = "VersionTLS13"
    cipherSuites = [
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
    ]
    curvePreferences = ["CurveP521", "CurveP384"]
    sniStrict = true

# API Configuration
[api]
  dashboard = true
  insecure = true

docker-compose.yml file
version: '3.3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    command:
      - --configFile=/traefik.toml
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/certs:/certs"
      - "./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`example`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure"

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`example`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=4000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints=websecure"
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    volumes:
      - ./backend/upload/images:/app/backend/upload/images

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`example`, `example`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=websecure"
    env_file:
      - ./frontend/.env

  admin:
    build: ./admin
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.admin.rule=Host(`example`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.admin.loadbalancer.server.port=5173"
      - "traefik.http.routers.admin.entrypoints=websecure"
    env_file:
      - ./admin/.env

SSL Checker states: (Check picture)
my LCN DNS records:
all A pointed to correct IP address
DNS check states resolved
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-lon1-01:/home/root/example# docker exec -it $(docker ps -qf "name=example_traefik_1") sh -c 'ls -l /certs; cat /traefik.toml'
total 8
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2244 Jun 24 10:53 certificate.crt
-rw-------    1 root     root          1704 Jun 20 14:49 private.key
# Entry Points Configuration
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.websecure.http.tls]

# Providers Configuration
[providers]
  [providers.docker]
    endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault = false

# TLS Certificates Configuration
[tls]
  [[tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "/certs/certificate.crt"
    keyFile = "/certs/private.key"
    stores = ["default"]

# TLS Stores Configuration
[tls.stores]
  [tls.stores.default]
    [tls.stores.default.defaultCertificate]
      certFile = "/certs/certificate.crt"
      keyFile  = "/certs/private.key"

# TLS Options Configuration
[tls.options]
  [tls.options.default]
    minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
    maxVersion = "VersionTLS13"
    cipherSuites = [
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
    ]
    curvePreferences = ["CurveP521", "CurveP384"]
    sniStrict = true

# API Configuration
[api]
  dashboard = true
  insecure = true

Completely lost on what i'm missing or doing wrong?
Why is it still assigning the default and not my custom certificate?

TLS is loaded via dynamic config in Traefik (doc), so you need a separate dynamic config file, which you load in static config via providers.file.
